# UISearchBar : How to prevent Cancel Button from clearing text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar

I have a screen with an `UISearchBar` within my app. It might be that there is already text in the searchbar, when the user enters the screen. **If the user then taps into the field and then taps cancel, the content of the searchbar should not be cleared.**

Is this achievable? I tried to implement `searchBarCancelButtonClicked`, but my modifications to the text property were ignored and the text field was still cleared.

Comment: Did you set the delegate appropriately?

Comment: Use `UISearchBar` without `cancel` button

Comment: @Guilherme: Yes, i am seeing a test log statement getting printed.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr: And how is the user then supposed to cancel his operation (defocusing the searchbar).

Comment: @mavilein try setting custom selector to `cancel` button.

Comment: How can i assign a custom selector for the `cancel` button? It does not seem obvious how to get a reference to this button.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran in to this same problem and solved it by manually tracking the state of whether the cancel button was pressed. If it is, reset the text when the searchBar ends editing, as modifying `searchBar.text` in `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` doesn't work:

This is what I did in my `UISearchBarDelegate` class:

```
var searchTerms = ""
var searchWasCancelled = false

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchWasCancelled = false
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchWasCancelled = true
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    if searchWasCancelled {
        searchBar.text = self.searchTerms
    } else {
        searchTerms = searchBar.text
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a strange behaviour here. It almost works fine but if I type in something, then press the search button and afterwards cancel it, the `searchBarTextDidEndEditing` delegate method does never get called and the `searchBar` gets cleared.

Comment: @palme use method with `_`: `func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)`

Comment: As written: "searchBarTextDidEndEditing delegate method does never get called".

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an update on this, as of iOS 15, it looks like changes in iOS 15 alter the order of which the `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` and `searchBarTextDidEndEditing` delegate methods are called.

Prior to iOS 15, a stateful solution such as the following would work for most use cases:

```swift
var searchTerms = ""
var searchWasCancelled = false

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchWasCancelled = false
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchWasCancelled = true
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    if searchWasCancelled {
        searchBar.text = self.searchTerms
    } else {
        searchTerms = searchBar.text
    }
}
```

Sadly, this breaks in iOS 15 and after some quick investigation, I can see that the `searchBarTextDidEndEditing` delegate method is always called prior to the `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` method. It’s unclear if this was an intended change by Apple or if it is indeed a bug.

All things aside, I've found a simple workaround to the original question and found that setting the `searchBar.text` from an async dispatch block, will successfully modify the text. Like so:

```swift
var previousSearchTerm = ""

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    previousSearchTerm = searchBar.text ?? ""
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        searchBar.text = self.previousSearchTerm
    }
}
```

Now this works for iOS 15 and prior, in my particular use case. However, depending what you're trying to achieve this may not be enough for backwards compatibility. It's also worth noting that this, like any other workaround modifying the stubborn default behaviour of UIKit, this comes with inherent risk of unknown side effects now or later on.