# UISearchController clears UISearchBar text when dismissed

Tags: ios, uikit, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

In `viewDidLoad` of my custom subclass of `UITableViewController`, I've set `navigationItem.titleView` to the `searchBar` of a `UISearchController`, which I initialized with `nil` for `searchResultsController`.

When I tap into the search bar, enter text, and tap on the dimmed underlying content, then the `UISearchController` gets deactivated (as expected) and the search text I entered gets cleared (unexpectedly).

The search text is also cleared (also unexpectedly) when I explicitly (programmatically) set the search controller to be inactive. To get around that, I store the search text before and set it back after dismissing the search controller. Although hacky, it works.

```
let searchText = searchBar.text // #hack
searchController.isActive = false
searchBar.text = searchText     // #hack
```

For when the search controller is automatically dismissed, I tried something similar using the `UISearchControllerDelegate` methods, i.e., storing the search text in `willDismissSearchController(_:)` and setting it back in `didDismissSearchController(_:)`. But, this solution still shows the search text getting cleared and then getting set back to what it was before.

How do I seamlessly keep the search bar text as is when the search controller is dismissed automatically?

Comment: uisearchbar delegate.

Comment: How could the search bar's delegate keep the search controller from clearing its text?

Comment: uisearchbar delegate method i have demo but now i m not near computer

Comment: Maybe you should create a custom search controller and add a custom searchbar property to it. Then declare the custom delegate for the search controller and searchbar.

Comment: subclass `UISearchBar` ?

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, but please provide more explanation. I tried subclassing `UISearchController` & `UISearchBar`, but neither `willSet` or `didSet` of `UISearchController.isActive` or `set` of `UISearchBar.text` seem to get called when the search controller is dismissed automatically.

Comment: OK, I got it! Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 6):

For *explicitly (programmatically)* dismissing the search controller, `UISearchController` is a view controller, so you can just call `dismiss(animated:completion:)` on it rather than setting `isActive = false` and resetting the search text:

```
searchController.dismiss(animated: true)
```

The search bar text will still persist in the search bar after dismissing.

Comment: this is a gem, I've been struggling with this problem and hacking around using `didDismissSearchController` function but was annoyed by the lag, this solved everything and also avoids tons of storing/controlling of the current state!

Answer (score 1):

In `searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_:)`, set `searchBar.text` back to what it was before.

See: [UISearchBar : How to prevent Cancel Button from clearing text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762859/uisearchbar-how-to-prevent-cancel-button-from-clearing-text)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by comparing one of [Apple's sample projects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/displaying_searchable_content_by_using_a_search_controller) to my own. As it turns out, you want to show your results in a separate table view controller than in the unfiltered data. Before you initialize your UISearchController, set up a separate TableViewController, and when you initialize your UISearchController, send the separate table view controller as the `searchResultsController:` argument.

```swift
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: 
                       self.searchResultsController)
```

Then in the `updateSearchResults(for:)` method I called `self.searchResultsController.tableView.reloadData()` after filtering my results.

This separate view controller will make the search controller behave in the way you would expect. I know that it's not by far a simple solution. In the interest of displaying search results in a way that makes it feel like they are being presented in the same table view as the unfiltered data, I'm not sure why Apple designed it this way but that's how it goes.